# Empty result from API call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[upn]/calendarGroups/[id]/calendars

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

I succeed with all calls to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[upn]/calendarGroups/[id]/calendars except when I send the group ID of the 'People's Calendars' built-in group. By the way, that group gets populated via 'import calendar'.

[image]

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Or is this known behaviour for that group?

Comment: I've not seen the "people's calendars" showing up in any of my tenants experiences. Is this something specific in your tenant that has been created? You say its a built-in group? where is that screen shot taken from? OWA calendar view for that group?

Comment: The screen shot is from https://outlook.office365.com/calendar. As soon as one imports a calendar, that 'People's Calendars' group shows up as the parent group.

Comment: sorry for delay here. How are you exactly importing the calendar?

Comment: At outlook.office365.com/calendar, just above 'My calendars' I click the 'Import Calendar' link. In the dialog I then choose 'From directory' and specify someone from my organization.

Comment: BTW, for my use case I've decided to create my own calendar group anyway and use that instead of the built-in People's Calendars group. So this is not blocking me.